# Write Output in table format in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

```
function Get-PCinfo {
    <#
    .Synopsis
        Short description
    .DESCRIPTION
       Long description
    .EXAMPLE
       Example of how to use this cmdlet
    .EXAMPLE
       Another example of how to use this cmdlet
    .NOTES
        <Zadanie 5>
        <Author email>
    #>
    
    
        [CmdletBinding()]
    
        Param(
            # Param1 help description
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,
                       ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                       Position=0)]
            [string[]]$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
    
            ## Param2 help description
            #[int]
            #[switch]$outFile = $false
        )
    
    Begin{
            $Info =  @()
    
            $Info | Format-List
                
        }
         Process{
    foreach ($computer in $ComputerName) {
    $NotReachableComputers=$null
        Write-Host "Testing connectivity $computer ..... please wait" -ForegroundColor White            
    if (Test-Connection $computer -Quiet -Count 1) {
            Get-CimInstance win32_UserAccount | ForEach-Object {
                $PCInfo = [PSCustomObject]@{
                
                ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
                Name = [string](Get-CimInstance win32_UserAccount).Name
                SID  = [string](Get-CimInstance win32_UserAccount).SID
                Lockout = [string](Get-CimInstance win32_UserAccount).Lockout
                Disabled = [string](Get-CimInstance win32_UserAccount).Disabled
                LocalAdminMember= $_.LocalAdminMember } 
            }
        }
        else {
            $NotReachableComputers += $computer.name
        }
    }
    }
        End{
        
            if($NotReachableComputers -ne $null){
            Write-Host "This system is not available on network" -ForegroundColor Red
            Write-Host $NotReachableComputers
            }
            else
            {
            Write-Host "Code worked on all PCs" -ForegroundColor Green
            Write-Output $PCInfo
            
            }
             #List of systems that were not available on the network
             #List of output from systems that were available
             #List where the output file is located
        }
    
    }
```

My problem is that the output is all together but I want it separately

So my output look like this
[image]

Or like this

[image]

What I want is to have a table like

```
ComputerName      Name     SID   .....
PCname            Name1    SID1 ......
PCname            Name2    SID2.....
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does your existing script find more than one computer?

Comment: Have you tried Format-Table?

Answer (score 1):

Your function never specifies `-ComputerName $computer` for your `Get-CimInstance` commands. This means it **only** ever runs on the local machine. Try and update it like so:

```
foreach ($computer in $ComputerName) {
  if (Test-Connection $computer -Quiet -Count 1) {
    Get-CimInstance win32_UserAccount -ComputerName $computer
```

The function does not specify which user's details you want within `$PCInfo`. You also do not need to query multiple times since your query is identical for each user's properties. Use `Select-Object` instead to include multiple properties. Aditionally, you can speed up the process by filtering for only the local accounts with `-Filter "LocalAccount=True"`:

```
$PCInfo = foreach ($computer in $ComputerName) {
  Write-Host "Testing connectivity $computer ..... please wait" -ForegroundColor White
  if (Test-Connection $computer -Quiet -Count 1) {
    Get-CimInstance win32_UserAccount -ComputerName $computer -Filter "LocalAccount=True" | 
      Select-Object Name,SID,Lockout,Disabled,LocalAdminMember
  }
}
Write-Output $PCInfo
```

And two more general points:

- `Win32_UserAccount` objects do not contain a property with the name `LocalAdminMember`. You would need to find that information a different way.
- `Test-Connection $computer` fails when `$computer` is the local machine

Answer (score 1):

#1 PSSession would be better for this.

#2 Your problem is here:

```
Get-CimInstance win32_UserAccount | ForEach-Object {
                $PCInfo = [PSCustomObject]@{
                
                ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
                Name = [string](Get-CimInstance win32_UserAccount).Name
                SID  = [string](Get-CimInstance win32_UserAccount).SID
                Lockout = [string](Get-CimInstance win32_UserAccount).Lockout
                Disabled = [string](Get-CimInstance win32_UserAccount).Disabled
                LocalAdminMember= $_.LocalAdminMember } 
            }
```

Running this command like this just runs "Get-CimInstance win32_UserAccount" 4 different times. Each time the command is run it returns an array when you then pend .Name  ,to the result i.e.(command).Name, selects the property "Name" from all the objects in the array, finally you are storing them against the key "Name" in the new PSCustomObject. that is why you are getting the second output above.

You should be running it like this:

> $PCInfo will be initilized as an empty system.array

```
$PCInfo = @()
```

> Get-CimInstance will be run one time then its results will be sent through the pipe | to the foreach-object this processes each object, selects the property for the individual object processed, then appends it to the PCInfo system array (+= does this for you)

```
Get-CimInstance win32_UserAccount | ForEach-Object {
                 $PCInfo += [PSCustomObject]@{

                 ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
                 Name = $_.Name
                 SID  = $_.SID
                 Lockout = $_.Lockout
                 Disabled = $_.Disabled
                 LocalAdminMember= $_.LocalAdminMember }
             }
```

After this **$PCInfo | Format-Table** should give it to you in the manner you are looking for.